# How to pass x and y axis values for creating a bar-chart in android?

Tags: android, bar-chart

How to pass the x-axis and y-axis values to the bar-chart for creating a bar-chart in android.Here i preferred AchartEngine method for creating a bar-chart in android.

But the problem is, i am getting the those values ie. x and y-axis values from the web service.I have successfully consumed these values but i am unable to pass those values to the bar-chart.
How to do this? suggestions please.

Thanks in advance!..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using `int[] series`  use

```
 static ArrayList<Integer> series = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

and update this series using ur values taken from web service.

like if u collect web service valuse in a `int[] webseries`

```
for (int i =0; i< webseries.Lenght; i++)
{ 
 series.add(webseries[i]); //series.add(newvlue);
}
```

and then repaint every time u add data it ll be dynamically updating as and when data available